# How to delete the string from each sublist that contains a string and a number and join the remaining numbers into one list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd appreciate help with the following:

I have a function called `Fun1` that will take a list such as

```
['Jo, 60, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
```

and turn it into

```
[['Jo', 77.3], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]]
```

It takes the average of the three numbers that belong to each person and then splits each person with their average into a sublist.

Now I want to create a new function called `Fun2` that takes the output from 
`Fun1` and turns it into one list with only the `int`s from `Fun1` output.

For instance, if Fun1 output is

```
[['Jo', 77.3], ['Bill', 65.0], ['Cal', 98.0]]
```

I want `Fun2` to give

```
[77.3, 65.0, 98.0]
```

Does anyone know of a way I can do this? I know I have to somehow delete the name from each sublist in the `Fun1` output and then join the numbers together in one list or put all the sublists together then delete all the name strings.

I know maybe some for loop and using del list[index] might be able to be used but I am lost as to how I can use them. I try and things don't work out.

Comment: It would be best to let us see what you have tried. And show us any errors produced by your code. And Some times creating new lists are easier than deleting elements from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def fun2():
    fun2out = []
    fun1out = fun1('initial list input here')
    for item in fun1out:
        fun2out.append(item[1])
    return fun2out
```

This funtion fun2 gets the returned list of lists and stores it as fun1out (fun1 output). The for loop access each list and the appends the number to the fun2 output.

Answer (score 0):

lets start with importing numpy as np

```
import numpy as np
def fun1(p:list):
    fun1_list=[]
    for i in p:
        c=[]
        temp = i.split(",")
        c.append(temp[0])
        results = list(map(float,temp[1:]))
        c.append("{:0.1f}".format(np.mean(results)))
        fun1_list.append(c)
    #print(fun1_list)#remove #to print the result
    return fun1_list
def fun2(f:fun1):
    fun2_list=[]
    for i in f:
        fun2_list.append(i[1])
    #print(fun2_list)  #remove #to print the result
    return fun2_list

fun_result= fun1(['Jo, 60, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'] )

fun2(fun_result)
```

Ans:
func1 list `[['Jo', '77.3'], ['Bill', '65.0'], ['Cal', '98.0']]`

func2 list `['77.3', '65.0', '98.0']`